# Which ASP.NET Windows Container Image to use in ECS? Windows Docker Container compatability issues in base image with Amazon ECS

Tags: asp.net, windows, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I have created a Dockerfile like so, for deploying my ASP.NET application:

```
# The `FROM` instruction specifies the base image. You are
# extending the `microsoft/aspnet` image.

FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1709

#WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

# The final instruction copies the site you published earlier into the container.
COPY ./bin/Release/Publish/ /inetpub/wwwroot
```

Now according to the documentation, this should use Windows Server build 10.0.14393.  However, when I build this container, push it to Amazon Elastic Container Registry, and then deploy this container image into Amazon Elastic Container Service [ECS] (running on Windows EC2 machines), I get this error:

> CannotPullContainerError: a Windows version 10.0.16299-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host

Has anyone had any success deploying ASP.NET Windows Docker Containers to Amazon ECS?  If so, which base image did you use?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Also tried this base image and it gives the same exact error: microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

Answer (score 0):

1709 images are not compatible with sac-2016 host os. Either you need to upgrade your host os to 1709 or downgrade your container image to sac-2016

Comment: But what is the name of that image?  I tried updating to this one and it also doesn't work: microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016